# Given that we have the radius of this line and the coordinate A, how can we calculate the coordinate C?

Tags: trigonometry, algebra, calculus

[image]

Given we have the radius of this circle and the coordinates of A, how can I calculate the coordinate of C? C is also at the furthest part away from the line, or in other words a line going form A to C would be rotated 90 degrees from the line  passing through A.

I tried using a substitution of the distance between point A and point C into the line equation for A, but I just can't seem to get the maths right for it.

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO! I would recommend reading through [SO tour page](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and through Help Center on what is considered [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here. This question seems more suited for [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) rather then SO.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure all the information you have, but assuming you have the vertex of the circle, example 3 gets the shortest distance, which would provide the line you need through the vertex as the other point of the line on the circle would be the longest distance.
https://www.varsitytutors.com/hotmath/hotmath_help/topics/shortest-distance-between-a-point-and-a-circle